# Ubuntu 20.04LTS No bluetooth found

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, bluetooth

[image: img_Bluetooth_not_found]

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.94 LTS with Windows 10 by using dual boot. But I am facing Bluetooth not found error and this is causing errors while booting Ubuntu
`failed to send firmware data (-110)`
Bluetooth is working fine in Windows 10.

Machine Info
HP spectre 360x convertible
Bios has no bluetooth setting

Please help me out

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for bluetooth after executing this command:

```
sudo rmmod btusb; sleep 1; sudo modprobe btusb
```